# Kronecker product of two irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose, I have two irreps $D^\mu(R)$ with dimension $n^\mu$  and $D^\nu(R)$ with dimension $n^\nu$ such that $n^\mu>n^\nu$ For $\forall R \in G$.Direct product of these two irreps will be reducible which means that it can be reduced to its irreducible bits. Suppose, One of those irreducible representation is $D^\sigma$ with dimension $n^\sigma$. My question- Is it possible to have an irrep with $n^\sigma<n^\mu/n^\nu$

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it is very unclear which generality you are asking in. Using the term "direct product" when you clearly mean "tensor product" seems to suggest this stems from physics? So are you asking about irreps for a Lie group or Lie algebra, or something more general?

Comment: For general finite groups.

Answer (score 0):

Using Schur's Orthogonality, we have that for finite groups the number of times a representation $D^{\bar{\sigma}}$ is contained in $D^{\mu}\otimes D^{\nu}$ is the same under interchange of $\sigma,\mu$ and $\nu $ (Here, $D^{\bar{\sigma}}$ denotes the adjoint representation of $D^{\sigma}$).

Now, suppose the representation $\lambda$ is in $D^{\mu}\otimes D^{\nu}$. Since $D^{\lambda}\sim D^{\bar{\sigma}}$ for some $\sigma$, we have $D^{\bar{\sigma}}$ is in $D^{\mu}\otimes D^{\nu} \Rightarrow D^{\mu}$ is in $D^{\bar{\sigma}}\otimes D^{\nu} $. Counting dimensions, we get $n_{\mu}\le n_{\bar{\sigma}}n_{\nu}$. Since $\bar{\sigma}\sim \lambda$, we get $n_{\lambda}\ge \frac{n_{\mu}}{n_{\nu}}$ which is what we needed to show.